# How to pass ellipsis argument to makecontext, which also accepts ellipsis argument in C?

Tags: c, ellipsis, ucontext

I have a function that runs other functions, and these functions can have a variable number of arguments.

The parameter of this function is then passed to `makecontext`, which attaches the function to a *ucontext_t* structure, but the problem is this function also takes variable number of arguments.

So my question is, how do I pass ellipsis argument obtained from a function to *makecontext* given that I can't change *makecontext*?

```
void run_function(void (*func), int argc, ...) {
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl, argc);
    
    makecontext(&ucontext, argc, ...);
    va_end(vl);
}
```

Comment: Short answer is you can't.  That's why variadic functions in C often have versions which take a `va_list` (*e.g.*, `printf`/`vprintf`).  Longer answer is it's possible, but you'll need to use something like [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/).  This is a comment not an answer because I'm too lazy to explain how.

Comment: Another possibility is using a variadic macro instead of a function for `run_function`.  For compilers which support statement expressions (basically most non-Microsoft compilers) that's probably pretty feasible…

Comment: i figured so. just wanted to clarify. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments by @nemequ, with a compiler like `gcc`, it is possible to use a variadic macro. But

- The *va_start()* macro needs at least one parameter before the variable number of parameters: the ***last*** parameter is the name of the last argument before the variable argument list;
- The function *func()* passed to *makecontext()* is passed the variable number of parameters but not the *argc* parameter when it is called.

Hence, the macro wrapper forces *argc* as first parameter for *func()* to make it use *va_start()*:

```c
#include <ucontext.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define run_function(ucp, func, argc, ...) \
           makecontext(ucp, func, (argc) + 1, argc, ##__VA_ARGS__)

typedef void (* ucfunc_t)(void);

void func1(int argc, ...)
{
  va_list ap;
  int param;
  int i;

  va_start(ap, argc);

  printf("func1() running with %d parameters:\n", argc);
  for (i = 0; i < argc; i ++) {
    param = va_arg(ap, int);
    printf("\t%d\n", param);
  }

  va_end(ap);
}

int main(void)
{
  ucontext_t main_uc, uc1, uc2, uc3;
  char stack1[4096], stack2[4096], stack3[4096];

  getcontext(&uc1);
  uc1.uc_link = &main_uc;
  uc1.uc_stack.ss_sp = stack1;
  uc1.uc_stack.ss_size = sizeof(stack1);

  getcontext(&uc2);
  uc2.uc_link = &uc1;
  uc2.uc_stack.ss_sp = stack2;
  uc2.uc_stack.ss_size = sizeof(stack2);

  getcontext(&uc3);
  uc3.uc_link = &uc2;
  uc3.uc_stack.ss_sp = stack3;
  uc3.uc_stack.ss_size = sizeof(stack3);

  run_function(&uc1, (ucfunc_t)func1, 0);
  run_function(&uc2, (ucfunc_t)func1, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
  run_function(&uc3, (ucfunc_t)func1, 2, 1, 2);

  getcontext(&main_uc);
  main_uc.uc_link = NULL;

  swapcontext(&main_uc, &uc3);

  return 0;
}
```

The previous example gives:

```
$ gcc ex1.c -o ex1
$ ./ex1 
func1() running with 2 parameters:
    1
    2
func1() running with 5 parameters:
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
func1() running with 0 parameters:
```